# Unable to pass Math.random() value to spring controller

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, google-app-engine

```
  var goal =$("#title").val();
  var desc =$("#desc").val();
  var id =Math.random()*1000;
  var data="suggest=" + goal + "&sugg=" + desc + "&projectid=" + id;

 $.ajax({
       url: '/Projectpage',
       type: 'POST',
       data: data ,
       error: function() {
       $('p').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
       },

       success: function(data) {
        $('p').html(data);        
       },
```

is my java script code

```
 $ @RequestMapping(value ="/Projectpage",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editProjectpage(@RequestParam("suggest") String name, @RequestParam("sugg") String desc, @RequestParam("projectid") String id)
{
    DatastoreService es = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    Entity e = new Entity("new project", id);
    e.setProperty("name", name);
    e.setProperty("desc",desc);
    es.put(e);

    return "html/Projectpage"; 
}
```

this is my code in spring controller.

Problem: In passing id value.

if I pass id as 123(like integer) in java script I can able to get the id in the spring controller.
If i change to Random number in js , I can't able to get it.

I don't know were I missed. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.random() returns decimal number like 0.43594394 instead use

```
 var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1)
```

this returns an integer value between 1 and 1000.

Comment: Hi Williams, I tried it out . it was working. Previously i had some problems in data store too. I can't understand why float values are not working